# Запрет ввода в input type="number"

Tags: html, css

Можно ли запретить ввод числа в `<input type="number">`, чтобы могли пользоваться только стрелками вверх/вниз?

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button  { 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="10" min="10">
```

Comment: Поле ввода в которое нельзя ничего ввести это странно, можете добавить атрибут `readonly`.

Comment: @pavel не, он имеет в виду типа ввод только стрелками

Comment: @dDevil ответ отправился на доработку, или с концами был удалён? Я хотел было написать, что за inline JS (пусть даже и только ради краткости) полагается расстрел, но не успел. Не знаю насчет планшетов (протестировать не на чем), но на компьютере вроде как хватает обработки событий `input` и `paste`: https://jsfiddle.net/994u8aru/.

Comment: @Regent решил удалить, так как решение не подходит для мобилок

Comment: @dDevil а что насчет моего варианта? Тоже не работает на мобильных устройствах?

Comment: @Regent ага, аналогично

Comment: @Regent, по вашей ссылке тоже наблюдается inline JS, поправьте и проверьте свой способ.

Comment: @Regent лично у меня возможно впихнуть `'.'` `','`, а автору ваще удалось какой-то магией пятерку засунуть

Comment: @Regent в этом варианте теперь и с десктопа можно тащить символы

Comment: @dDevil зря я второпях просто удалил код. Добавил в список обработчиков: https://jsfiddle.net/994u8aru/2/. Насчет мобильных устройств у меня идей нет.

Comment: @Regent, Попробовал какимто обрахом возможно удалить цифру 10 способом shift + 1-2-3-4-5,shift + 4 добавляет +

Comment: @Regent, Убрал весь код js оставил в html `onkeydown="return false"` и всё работает вроде

Comment: @Sauron вам уже объясняли, что на мобильных устройствах не работает. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, в моём коде тоже есть блокировка события `keydown`. А писать `onkeydown="return false"` вообще ни разу не здорово.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант c JavaScript:

```
<input type="number" id="check"/>

<script>
document.getElementById('check').onkeypress = function (e) {
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Или так:

```
<input type="number" id="check" onkeypress="return false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

<input type="number" value="10" min="10" **disabled**>